# How to UPDATE a query with different arguments in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

### Environment

> Node.js, MySQL (using `node-mysql library` connect)

### At first

I could have `one argument 'aaa'` or `two arguments 'aaa' and 'bbb'`.

```
UPDATE user SET email = 'aaa' WHERE uid = 'xxx';
UPDATE user SET email = 'aaa', password = 'bbb' WHERE uid = 'xxx';
```

### My problem

How could I use one query to overcome above cases? Like below ...

```
var sql = "UPDATE user SET email = ?, password = ? WHERE uid = ?;"
dbclient.query(sql, [email, password, uid], function (err, results) {
    ...
});
```

1. If two arguments were `defined`, variable `sql` was :

   ```
   sql = "UPDATE user SET email = 'test@mail.com', password = 'abcd' WHERE uid = 1;";
   ```
2. If someone argument was `undefined`, variable `sql` was :

   ```
   sql = "UPDATE user SET email = 'test@mail.com', password = password WHERE uid = 1;";
   ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read the documentation, especially the section [escaping query values](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values). `node-mysql` supports some neat use of object serialization.

The following example should be what you want (it uses format, but so does `query()` internally):

```
var mysql = require( 'mysql' );

var credfull = {
        email: "a@exemple.com",
        password: "secret"
    },
    crednopwd = {
        email: "a@exemple.com"
    },
    whereclause = {
        uid: "blabla"
    };

console.log( mysql.format( 'UPDATE user SET ? WHERE ?', [credfull, whereclause]) );
// UPDATE user SET `email` = 'a@exemple.com', `password` = 'secret' WHERE `uid` = 'blabla'

console.log( mysql.format( 'UPDATE user SET ? WHERE ?', [crednopwd, whereclause]) );
// UPDATE user SET `email` = 'a@exemple.com' WHERE `uid` = 'blabla'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much!! I read the part **#Escaping query identifiers**, no wonder no progress :P